# Memory Limit for CodeIgniter Zip Library

Tags: codeigniter, zip, archive

is there any way to overcome a memory limitation while compressing a large directory with the codeigniter zip library. I have roughly 4,000 pdfs I'm trying to backup.

can I use an

`INI SET('memory_limit, 'XXXM');`

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that will update the memory_limit for the session. However, it might be better to throttle a call to a script that will do a subset of pdfs.